# Running function app with Azure Active Directory authentication from Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have function app (http trigger) in which I've registered with Azure Active Directory.

When I open a browser and invoke the endpoint, I'm getting the certificate token from AD and after confirmation I've been redirected to the function app itself - all works as expected.

My issue is: how can I run it from Azure pipeline, as all the job run is managed by the agent without any prompts to confirm the certificate from AD?

There is no interactive way to confirm the token in order to proceed to the function app.

I've tried also using service principal for resource type but still getting 401 "UNAUTHORIZED".

Any ideas please?

Comment: in Azure pipeline you can manage particular job manually as well. you just need to configure the agent. Agent should not to do the confirmation for azure ad token automatically it should be manually by you. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: You need to create a service connection in ADO project that is authorized to access the Function app. The pipeline or a step should be configured to use this service connection.